# Creación de carpetas con Python en FTP

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

Estoy buscando la opción de crear una estructura de carpetas año/mes/día con el módulo de Ftplib de Python

Conexión:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_servidor, ftp_usuario, ftp_clave)
```

Cargando variables:

```
ftp_raiz     = 'example/'

filename = '2019-10-01T00-00-00.txt'
```

Función

```
def cdTree(ftp, filename=None, path=None):

    if filename is not None:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.txt')
        path = ftp_raiz + date.strftime('%Y') + '/' + date.strftime('%m') + '/' + date.strftime('%d')
        print filename
    if path != "":
        try:
            ftp.cwd(path)
        except error_perm as e:
            print e, ", creating folder"
            print path
            cdTree(ftp, path="/".join(path.split("/")[:-1]))
            ftp.mkd(path)
            ftp.cwd(path)

cdTree(ftp, filename, 'TEST')
```

Finalmente no me crea la estructura de carpetas, y me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Entre el volcado de la excepción puede leerse `error_perm`, que hace pensar en un problema de permisos.

Comment: Realice la prueba de crear solo una carpeta y paso sin problemas